Transfer files from a HDFS directory to a remote Linux server
We have a requirement to transfer files from an HDFS directory to a remote server.
I've noticed options to copy files from HDFS to the local filesystem first (using copyToLocal) and then transfer files from the local filesystem to the remote server (using scp). But is there any direct method to copy files from HDFS to a remote server, such as using Sqoop export functionality or any other methods like without copying to the local file system. The remote server does not support Hadoop-compatible file systems so I cannot use DistCp command. Also, we would like to achieve this functionality without using Nifi.
copyToLocal & scp commands
